# Unable to generate text in the scene when clicking a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So having a bit of an issue. I have a button which when clicked will read an XML file which gets read into memory, I have removed some segments of unwanted text, and now want it to display that text on Unity Scene. I have debugged and it has got to the point it can read the text in debug, however, it will not produce the text on screen. I have used GUILabel which SHOULD output text on screen but its not doing so. Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEditor; 
public class ReadFile  {


// Use this for initialization
public static void startRead()
{
    XmlDocument curDoc = new XmlDocument ();
    curDoc.Load (Application.dataPath + "\\File\\test.xml");
    if (curDoc.ChildNodes.Count > 0) 
    {
        foreach(XmlNode curRoot in curDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            if(curRoot.ChildNodes.Count>0)
            {
                foreach(XmlNode curChild in curRoot.ChildNodes)
                  {  
                    string curUserData= (curChild.InnerText.Replace("%20"," ").Replace("true20","").Replace("%?F","?" + " ").Replace("%3F","?"));
                    Debug.Log(curUserData);
                    GUI.Label (new Rect (10,10,150,20), curUserData);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a UI -> Text gameobject in your scene, add a public Text property in your script, reference it via inspector, display text via text.text="my text"

Comment: Don't use the unity tag as it is for a different thing.

Comment: using UnityEngine.UI; is for the new UI that came with Unity 4.6 but GUI.Label() is part of the old UI. I suggest that you read a tutorial  for the new UI and you stop using the legacy UI because it will become obsolete.